# Is setting the Authorization header in HttpClient safe?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I'm working in a MVC5 ASP.NET project, and learned that to send authenticated requests to a WEB API from the controller I could do the following to add a token to the header(using an example code):

```
public static class APICaller
{
    // Use a single instance for HttpClient to reduce overhead
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    //Set the Authorization Header
    public static string SetHeader( string token )
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        return("Success");
    }
}
```

Is setting the header this way on the HttpClient thread-safe? Will other users have a way to access this same token, given that there is only one instance of this HttpClient?

EDIT:

I'd like to ask one more question to get a better understanding of how it works. Would I need to add the header each time I'm making a request with the same HttpClient object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the approach you have, once you've set the default request header on your static instance, it will remain set without you having to keep setting it. This means that if you have multiple requests coming into your server, you could end up in a situation where the header is set for one user and then changed by another request before that first request makes it out the door.

One option to avoid this would be to use [`SendAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138176(v=vs.118).aspx) when using user-specific authorisation headers. This allows you to tie the header to a specific message, rather than setting it as a default for the `HttpClient` itself.

The code is a bit more verbose, but would look something like this:

```
using (var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://path/to/wherever"))
{
    httpRequestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "TheToken");

    using (var httpResponseMessage = httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, the header is set specially on each request and therefore the issue of mixing up the headers goes away. The obvious downside is that this syntax is more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

> Will other users have a way to access this same token, given that there is only one instance of this HttpClient?

Yes, that is why you need to be careful when setting the default headers.

> Would I need to add the header each time I'm making a request with the same HttpClient object?

No, because you set the *default* header all requests created with that object will have the header.

For things like a Bearer token it is better to not put in the default headers and instead put it in the request header by creating a new `HttpRequestMessage` object, setting the headers you need there, then using `HttpClient.SendAsync(`  passing in the request message to send the headers along with your request.