# Setting request headers per request with IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, httpclientfactory

I'm using typed clients with `IHttpClientFactory`. Like this:

```
// Startup.cs
services.AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>()

// MyHttpClient.cs
public class MyHttpClient
{
    public MyHttpClient(HttpClient client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public HttpClient Client { get; }
}

// MyService.cs
public class MyService {
    public MyService(MyHttpClient httpClient) {}

    public async Task SendRequestAsync(string uri, string accessToken) {
        _httpClient.Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        await _httpClient.Client.GetAsync(uri);
    }
}
```

I'm unsure how this works. Will the request headers be set only for this request, or for every subsequent request that is made using this instance of `httpClient`. How can I set header on a per request basis?

Comment: You can use an `HttpRequestMessage` instead. And use it like this : `_httpClient.Client.SendAsync(myRequest)`

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338925/is-setting-the-authorization-header-in-httpclient-safe/47339061#47339061) gives a code example of how to implement @Kalten's approach.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [`DelegatingHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx) to add an header to each request the `HttpClient` will make.

```
public class HeaderHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    public HeaderHandler()
    {
    }
    public HeaderHandler(DelegatingHandler innerHandler): base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("CUSTOM-HEADER","CUSTOM HEADER VALUE");
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

}

You register the hanlder using :

```
service.AddTransient<HeaderHandler>()
    .AddHttpClient<MyHttpClient>()
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<HeaderHandler>();
```

Comment: How can we get configuration values from the `DelegatingHandler`?

Comment: @Jimenemex by DI