# HttpClient in MVC controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpclient, dnx

I have a question about `HttpClient`. I have an ASP.NET MVC 6 project. I need call some REST api for get or post some data.

Then I have next logic. User call a server method ip/index>> server get request and call api ip/api/GetSomething>> server get response and return View for user.

Sample code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
        try
        {
            using (var h = new HttpClient())
            {
                h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); //token i got early
                h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "true");
                h.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                string sQueryKadastr = _uRL + $"/api/GetSomething";

                contentSave.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                var response = await h.GetAsync(sQueryKadastr);
            
                //did something with response and return View
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            g_Global.Log.Write4Web(User.GetUserName(), $"Errors: ", ex);
        }

        return View("Error");
}
```

My method work good (any post, get, put etc), but I know that after using dispose HttpClient, the socket continues to live. And in the future I would can get SocketException.

How can I avoid this? I cannot use one `HttpClient` because requests to the server can go simultaneously from different users and they will probably conflict. I mean server can get request in Index action `[HttpGet]` and to Index action `[HttpPost]` and both method will set himself header to `HttpClient` and URI at same the time.

Or maybe I am doing something wrong? I would be grateful for any help.

Solution for safe thread:
[Is setting the Authorization header in HttpClient safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338925/is-setting-the-authorization-header-in-httpclient-safe)

Comment: [YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: ASP.NET  MVC **6** was renamed ASP.NET **Core MVC** - is that what you're using? Or did you just get the version number wrong ? (the last version on the "full" .NET Framework is ASP.NET MVC **5**)

Comment: I am using MVC 6 with DNX 1.0.0-rc1-update1

Comment: @Peter they know, it's literally in the question: _"I know that after using dispose HttpClient, the socket continues to live"_.

Comment: YOU'RE USING HTTPCLIENT WRONG – Peter Csala 7. I readed this post. And i ask how i can use httpClient one instance in MVC 6 if server can get many requests. For console aplication with one thread it's ok, but how about MVC 6.

Comment: HttpClient is thread-safe, but just use an HttpClientFactory: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: @CodeCaster, available since .NET Core 2.1

Comment: Yes, and? Are you stuck on DNX and MVC 6?

Comment: @CodeCaster, yeap, 
the organization in which I work uses this version and so far there is no way to switch to another, because translation will take a huge amount of time, more than development for the current task

Comment: Alright, but then you can register your own HttpClient with your IOC container. Or a factory, or, or, or. No need to new() one for every request. Again, it's thread safe.

Comment: @PeterCsala, yeap, thanks, but one more for this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47338925/is-setting-the-authorization-header-in-httpclient-safe.